# how to calculate birthdate from age (day , month ,year) and current date in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How to calculate birthdate based on age (day , month ,year) and current date
I tried this but the result appears incorrect
I can get age from birth date correctly  but getting birth date from age,  result appear different than origin birth date
sample when calculate age for 15/4/2022 and then calculate birth date for this age it appears 12/4/2022
[image]

```
Dim day, month, year As Integer
    day = CInt(NumDay.Value)
    month = CInt(NumMonth.Value)
    year = CInt(NumYear.Value)
    Dim dateResult As Date = Now
    DateTimePicker1.Value = dateResult.AddYears(-year).AddMonths(-month).AddDays(-day)




  Function AgeCalculator(ByVal FromDate As Date, Todate As Date, ByRef year As Integer, ByRef month As Integer, ByRef day As Integer, Optional flgyearOnly As Boolean = False) As String '23/11/2017
    If Not IsDate(FromDate) Then Return ""
    Dim tmpYear As String = "", tmpMonth As String = ""
    Dim tmpdiffDaya As Integer = 0
    Dim tmpAge As String = ""
    tmpdiffDaya = CInt(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, (FromDate), Todate))
    If tmpdiffDaya <= 0 Then Return ""
    If tmpdiffDaya > 0 And tmpdiffDaya <= 29 Then
        Return tmpdiffDaya & " Days"
    End If
    If tmpdiffDaya = 30 Then
        Return " 1 Month"
    End If
    tmpYear = CStr(tmpdiffDaya / 365)
    If InStr(tmpYear, ".") > 0 Then
        tmpYear = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(tmpYear, InStr(tmpYear, ".") - 1)
    End If
    year = CInt(tmpYear)
    If Val(tmpYear) = 0 Then tmpYear = ""
    If Val(tmpYear) > 0 Then
        tmpAge = tmpYear & " years"
        If flgyearOnly Then Return tmpAge
    End If

    tmpdiffDaya = CInt((tmpdiffDaya - (Val(tmpYear) * 365)))

    tmpMonth = CStr(tmpdiffDaya / 30)
    If InStr(tmpMonth, ".") > 0 Then
        tmpMonth = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(tmpMonth, InStr(tmpMonth, ".") - 1)

    End If
    month = CInt(tmpMonth)

    If Val(tmpMonth) = 0 Then
        tmpMonth = ""
    Else

        If CInt(tmpMonth) > 0 Then
            tmpAge &= "  " & tmpMonth & " Months"
        End If

    End If
    tmpdiffDaya = CInt((tmpdiffDaya - (Val(tmpMonth) * 30)))
    day = tmpdiffDaya
    If Val(tmpdiffDaya) > 0 Then
        tmpAge &= "  " & tmpdiffDaya & " Days"
    End If
    Return tmpAge
End Function
```

Comment: Why do you have variables declared as type `Double` with names starting with "int"? I hate Hungarian Notation at the best of times but Hungarian Notation that lies is a greater evil still.

Comment: Given that the `DateTime` type has `AddYears`, `AddMonths` and `AddDays` methods, determining a date that is a specific number of years, months and days before today's date should not be a challenge.

Comment: The result appears different , also i tried AddYears, AddMonths and AddDays   the result has different in days than expected ( see the picture)

Comment: You cannot calculate a birthdate from age and the current date. It's not enough information. Or do you mean that you want to calculate age from the birthdate for a given date?

Comment: I already can calculate age from birth date and return the exact age in years month and days and when it use this information to return the date it different from the origin birth date

Comment: @mazenmougi - It would really be helpful if you showed both calculations super clearly in your question. Can you provide code for the following two signatures: `Public Function GetDifference(ByVal dob As DateTime, ByVal now As DateTime) As (Years As Integer, Months As Integer, Days As Integer)` (which I understand you already can do) and for `Public Function GetDob(ByVal now As DateTime, years As Integer, months As Integer, days As Integer) As DateTime` (which is what I understand you're trying to do).

Comment: I update the  code and the picture with  addyears, addmonth,  adddays but still there is different 3 days when calculate age for 15/4/2022  and then calculate birth date for this age it appears 12/4/2022

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `AddDays` first, then `AddMonths`, then `AddYears`. If you wanted to calculate a person's age in years, months and days then you would calculate the years first, then the months, then the days. If you're doing the calculation the other way, you have to actually do it the other way. If you subtract years first then a leap year could throw the calculation out. If you subtract months before days then that calculation will be affected by the different numbers of days in each month.

```vb
Private Function GetPastDate(years As Integer, months As Integer, days As Integer) As Date
    Return Date.Today.AddDays(-days).AddMonths(-months).AddYears(-years)
End Function
```

My date of birth is June 19, 1969, which means that I am 53 years, 1 month and 16 days old today (August 4, 2022). If I use the method above with those numbers then I get the correct date of birth. If I call those methods the opposite way around, I get June 18 instead of 19.

EDIT:

I haven't looked closely but it appears that your `AgeCalculator` doesn't work. I just tested the following code:

```vb
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim dateOfBirth = #4/15/2012#
        Dim years As Integer
        Dim months As Integer
        Dim days As Integer

        CalculateAge(dateOfBirth, years, months, days)

        Dim output = GetPastDate(years, months, days)
    End Sub

    Private Sub CalculateAge(dateOfBirth As Date, ByRef years As Integer, ByRef months As Integer, ByRef days As Integer)
        Dim temp As Date
        Dim currentDate = Date.Today

        dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth.Date

        years = 0
        months = 0

        Do
            temp = dateOfBirth.AddYears(1)

            If temp > currentDate Then
                Exit Do
            End If

            years += 1
            dateOfBirth = temp
        Loop

        Do
            temp = dateOfBirth.AddMonths(1)

            If temp > currentDate Then
                Exit Do
            End If

            months += 1
            dateOfBirth = temp
        Loop

        days = (currentDate - dateOfBirth).Days
    End Sub

    Private Function GetPastDate(years As Integer, months As Integer, days As Integer) As Date
        Return Date.Today.AddDays(-days).AddMonths(-months).AddYears(-years)
    End Function

End Module
```

and it worked as expected. The values of `years`, `months` and `days` were 10, 3 and 20 respectively and the value of `output` was `#4/15/2012#`, the same as the initial input.

Comment: the function agecalculator included show age different  than the sample

Comment: My code works correctly. It is your AgeCalculator method that is wrong. If someone's date of birth is April 15, 2012 then they are 10 years, 3 months and 20 days old today (August 4, 2022). If you plug those numbers into my method then you get the correct date of birth back. I haven't looked carefully at your `AgeCalculator` method but I can tell that it's garbage at a glance because I can see that it's using `Val` and `Left`. There's not reason to be using `Double` or `String` values. It should be all `Date` and `Integer`. I will provide a proper implementation.

Comment: @mazenmougi, see my edit, which demonstrates a correct age-calculation routine and the fact that my birthdate calculation routine works as it should.